# Solving ERROR at line 1274954: Unknown command '\'' in larger (100mb+) mysql .sql file

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

When running this on a file that is 100mb+:

```
$ mysql -u xxxx -p dbname < /path/to/dump.sql
```

I get:

```
ERROR at line 1274954: Unknown command '\''.
```

However, when I do this:

```
head -1274964 /path/to/dump.sql | tail -20
```

I simply get (**'INSERT INTO address' is line 1274954**, however I see no error anywhere):

```
    updated, updated_by,
    status, person,
    profile, measurements)
    VALUES
    ('0000-00-00 00:00:00', '2517',
    '0000-00-00 00:00:00', '2517',
    3, '2517',
    'Team', 'Team');

INSERT INTO address
    (created, created_by, 
    updated, updated_by, 
    status_id, person_id, 
    org_id,
    street_1, street_2,
    city, state, 
    postal, lng,
    lat, country_code)
    VALUES
    ('0000-00-00 00:00:00', '2517',
```

Comment: Post the surrounding lines too.

Answer (score 2):

Try running it with

```
 mysql --verbose -u xxxx -p db < file
```

this should give you a better idea of the problem - I cant remember if when it counts line numbers if its litteral or not - eg blank lines might not count..